# Importing a subclass when interface is not in subclass .jar

Tags: java, dynamic, jar, classloader

So i've decided to try to write a thing that will loads a specific .class file from a .jar that anyone puts into a folder. (Right now it only loads my Test.jar)
The thing is, that these classes implements an interface in the java project that i'm loading them from, and i get an error telling me that the class "Klass" doesn't exist.
How can i get the loader to load that one instead of trying to use it's own?
(Also, this is what i think it's doing, i have no idea if it's true)

The code for loading the .jar:

```
     String filePath = new String("C:/classes/Test.jar");

     URL myJarFile = null;
            try {
                myJarFile = new URL("file:///"+filePath);

                URL[] urls = new URL[]{myJarFile};

                // Create a new class loader with the directory
                ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

                // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
                // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompan
                Class cls = cl.loadClass("me.bluejelly.survivalgames.classes.Test");

                try {
                    Klass klass = (Klass) cls.newInstance();
                    klass.create(arg0.getName());
                    Main.listeners.put(arg0.getName(), klass);
                    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(klass, instance);
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And this it the code in the file i'm trying to load:

```
package me.bluejelly.survivalgames.classes;

import me.bluejelly.survivalgames.Main;
import me.bluejelly.survivalgames.def.Klass;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class Test implements Klass {

private String ownerName;

@Override
public void create(String pName) {
    this.ownerName = pName;
    Main.listeners.put(this.ownerName, this);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    if(Main.listeners.containsKey(this.ownerName)) {
        Main.listeners.remove(ownerName);
    }
    HandlerList.unregisterAll(this);
}

@Override
public Material getIcon() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public ItemStack[] getStartingItems() {
    return null;
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
    if(event.getPlayer().getName().equals(ownerName)) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("test");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the main class loader as the parent of your new URLClassLoader.  That way it will pick up your local Klass class.

Something like...

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll try it when I get home. I had to hurry to work.